# Execute a PHP function from image OnClick event

Tags: php, javascript

I have a PHP class in which there is a `delete` function. When I click on the image I want to call `delete`, but this line is not working:

```
echo "<img src='icon/del.gif'  onClick='.delete().'/>"
```

I have tried using the `href` tag but it doesn't work.

Comment: PHP runs on the server... The onclick event runs on the client...

Comment: THANKS  Macmade but if i want to do it for php how can i manage it

Comment: You have to send a request to the server that is running your PHP. The server can't magically see what events occur on the client unless you send it this information.

Comment: `<a href='delete.php?id=123'><img src='icon/del.gif' /></a>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering you can use jQuery, you need to do the following:

first give your img a class, for example:

```
<img src="/icon/del.gif" class="delete" />
```

then bind this using jquery:

```
$('.delete').click(function(){
   $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '/url/to/your_php_script.php',
      data: {'id':'45'}
      }
   });
});
```

your php file gets executed and $_POST['id'] gets send to it.

does this help? can you do the rest yourself? if not, give us more code :)

Answer (score 0):

- Create cross browser XHR.
- Request a URL which calls `delete()`.

Repeat with me: *JavaScript runs on the client; PHP runs on the server*.

PHP can echo JavaScript and JavaScript can make HTTP requests.